# Number theory question involving primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that, if a, b are prime numbers $a > b$, each containing at least two digits,
then $a^4 - b^4$ is divisible by $240$. Also prove that, $240$ is the gcd of all the numbers
which arise in this way.

Looking at the prime factorisation $240=(2^4)*3*5$, i know i need to prove that the given difference is divisible by each of these.

How do i proceed from here? i have no idea.
Thanks.

Comment: There seems to be a solution on [AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h308309p1665023), and some weaker proofs on this site [Prime numbers and divisibility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1161433/prime-numbers-and-divisibility)

Comment: Maybe the fact that a^4 - b^4 = (a^2 + b^2)(a+b)(a-b) could help.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts

Comment: $a^4\equiv1\bmod16$ (Carmichael), $a^4\equiv1\bmod5$ (Fermat), and $a^2\equiv1\bmod3$ (Fermat) if $\gcd(a,240)=1$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40429/11619) may be an even better duplicate target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$240 = 2^4 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$.  Any prime $> 5$ is coprime to $2, 3, 5$.  The fourth powers of odd numbers mod $2^4$ are all $1$, the fourth powers of $1$ and $2$ mod $3$ are $1$, and the fourth powers of $1,2,3,4$ mod $5$ are all $1$.  So the fourth power of any number coprime to $240$ mod $240$ is $1$.

The first three two-digit primes are $11, 13, 17$.
What is the gcd of $13^4-11^4$ and $17^4-11^4$?

Comment: Hmm i see.But how do i prove the gcd thing ( 240 is the gcd of all such numbers) in general?

Comment: "The gcd of all the numbers"  is $240$ if all the numbers are divisible by $240$ and there are two whose gcd is $240$. Did you compute the gcd of $13^4 - 11^4$ and $17^4-11^4$?

Comment: $240$ is the $gcd$. Oh waitttt. Now for all other numbers formed this way, even if someof them had a gcd greater than $240$, the aggregate gcd would still be $240$. Understood. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @robert israel How to solve this problem without using modular arithmetic. Because the book I'm referring has not introduced modular arithmetic yet.